# Jquery text replacement into a <a><span><span>text</a>

Tags: jquery, html, dom, text, replace

I try to change a text into this code :

```
<li>
    <a id="toggle-edition" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit page
    </a>
</li>
```

With

```
$("#toggle-edition").text('Save Page')
```

My span is removed :(

Comment: wrong, it doesn't replace old taxt and bootstrap render is altered. Always tried this. moreover, text is not wrapped into span but into link element$

Comment: That's because you are replacing the contents of the `<a>` tag. change the code to `$("Toggle-edition span").text(....);` and I think you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My span is removed* is the expected behavior as you are overwriting the content of `anchor` element.

Use the following code:

```js
$("#toggle-edition > span")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = 'Save Page';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="toggle-edition" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit page
    </a>
```

Comment: Old text is not replaced, and text is wrapped into span not anchor

Answer (score 1):

jQuery isn't designed to work on text/comment node. Use relevant plain js method, e.g:

```
$("#toggle-edition > span")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "Save Page";
```

More jQuery's like, it could be:

```
$("#toggle-edition").contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType === 3 && $(this.previousSibling).hasClass('glyphicon');
}).replaceWith('Save Page');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$("#toggle-edition").text('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Save Page');
```

Comment: should told without re-build the span element

Answer (score 0):

try to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var gettextr = $("#toggle-edition");
            var oldVal = gettextr.text();
            var NewStr = $(gettextr).html().replace($.trim(oldVal), 'Save Page');
            $(gettextr).html(NewStr);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

just reset html content

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         // save here your span element
         var tmpChild = $("#toggle-edition>:first-child");

         // set into <a> element your span 
         $("#toggle-edition").html( tmpChild);

         // enter new text value after your span
         tmpChild.after('new Value')

    });
```

so you will not replace element span, but insert after this span element new text

look here working code: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/lAFCfVkN2DsvGA0GQmvn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Text with an span and an Id. So you can use `$("#SpanID").html('Save page')` to change the Text without remove the previous Span

```
<a id="toggle-edition" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
<span id="SpanID"> Edit page </span> </a>
```